# Dynamic Parameter to stay selected

Tags: channel-entries, filter, dynamic, drop-down

I'm using Dynamic Parameters to filter through some channels
https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/dynamic_parameters.html

Is there a way to get the chosen select value to stay selected rather than it default back to the first option (All Tours in my case) after posting.

```
<form method="post" action="{path='template/{segment_2}'}">
          <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{csrf_token}" />
              <select name="channel">
                  <option value="llanelly-house-tour|restoration-tour|ghostly-tour">All Tours</option>
                  <option value="llanelly-house-tour">Llanelly House Tour</option>
                  <option value="restoration-tour">Restoration Tour</option>
                  <option value="ghostly-tour">Ghostly Tour</option>
              </select>
    </div>
    <div class="small-2 columns">
    <input role="button" aria-label="Submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="button postfix submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options here.

You could use [Mo' Variables](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) to get to the `{post:channel}` variable and use that in a conditional to add the `selected` attribute to your options.

You could also use [Dynamo](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dynamo), which offers even more functionality for dynamic parameters.

If you want to go all out, choosing a proper search/filtering add-on would be the way to go. Options are [Solspace Super Search](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/super-search) or [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) by yours truly.

Comment: Perfect thank you Low, plenty of options :)

Comment: Go Low Like A Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Low! Mo Variables worked perfectly. I used the following to select the post channel:

```
 <form method="post" action="{path='tour-calendar/{segment_2}'}">
          <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{csrf_token}" />
              <select name="channel">
                  <option {if post:channel == "a|b|c"} selected="selected"{/if} name="channel" value="a|b|c">All Tours</option>
                  <option {if post:channel == "a"} selected="selected"{/if} name="channel" value="a">Llanelly House Tour</option>
                  <option {if post:channel == "b"} selected="selected"{/if} name="channel" value="b">Restoration Tour</option>
                  <option {if post:channel == "c"} selected="selected"{/if} name="channel" value="c">Ghostly Tour</option>
              </select>
    </div>
    <div class="small-2 columns">
    <input role="button" aria-label="Submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="button postfix submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
```